# How to make "imports" array for module in Angular configurable?

Tags: angular

Let's say I want to write an Angular module called "alert-button". Each time I press the "alert-button", there should be an alert that says "Hi!". So my alert-button-component looks somewhat like this:

```
<button (click)="doAlert()">Alert!</button>
```

But now let's say, I want that the user of the module can use their own button together with my alert-module. So I'd try to do something like:

```
@NgModule({})
export class TaskModule {
  static forRoot(AppButtonModule)
    return {
      ngModule: TaskModule,
      imports: [AppButtonModule],
      providers: [AlertService]
    }
  }
}
```

So in **the module** I'm trying to use a **part of the caller**. The module's component then could look like this:

```
<app-button (click)="doAlert()">Alert!</app-button>
```

I could document my module for example with "provide your own button, so the module matches the style of your application". Every user of the module would have to provide the module with **another module** that has a component with the selector "app-button".

However, this exact way I've suggested above doesn't work, you can't simply put imports in the return of for root. Is there another way to achieve the desired behaviour? Maybe with lazy loading or something like that?

The goal is to get something like this:

[image]